# Is it possible to write a Python web scraper that plays an mp3 whenever an element's text changes?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, mp3

Trying to figure out how to make python play `mp3s` whenever a tag's text changes on an Online **Fantasy Draft Board** (`ClickyDraft`).

I know how to scrape elements from a website with python & beautiful soup, and how to play `mp3s`. But how do you think can I have it detect when a certain element changes so it can play the appropriate `mp3`?

I was thinking of having the program scrape the site every `0.5seconds` to detect the changes,

but I read that that could cause problems? Is there any way of doing this?

Comment: The problem you read was likely regarding making requests so frequently, every .5 seconds comes out to just under 200k requests per day which is pretty excessive. Some services might automatically ban or throttle you for making that many requests. If you dial that back to every few minutes and only while you are actively monitoring it would be less of an issue, you could also look to see if the service has an API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way is too scrape the site on a regular basis.  0.5s is too fast. I don't know how time sensitive this project is. But scraping every 1/5/10 minute is good enough. If you need it quicker, just get a proxy  (plenty of free ones out there) and you can scrape the site more often.

Just try respecting the site, Don't consume too much of the sites ressources by requesting every 0.5 seconds